# How to find basis of the image of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the basis of the image of the linear transformation given by the following matrix:

$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 0 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} $

I've tried looking online, but have become more confused.

I thought that you would just find a maximal linearly independent subset of the column vectors and then that would be the basis of the image (in which case it would be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $ or $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} $).

But I've heard that you have to first row reduce the matrix - why?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not unique, so it should be **a** basis, not **the** basis.

You are correct: a maximal linearly independent set of columns form a basis.  In this case any two columns are linearly independent, while of course all three are not,
so any two columns form a basis.  You don't need to row reduce the matrix, that's just a way of ensuring
the column you choose are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} x+ 2y+ 3z \\ y+ 3z\end{pmatrix}= x\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+ y\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+ z\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$

Those are three vectors but since they are in $R^2$ they cannot be independent.  We can write $\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$$= -3\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+ 3\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

So we can take $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ as basis.  But in fact, since those span all of $R^2$ we could take any two independent vectors as basis, even $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.